# Whom should he question

Tags: riddle

One snowy night, Sherlock Holmes was in his house sitting by a fire…
Snow outside...

… All of a sudden a snowball crashed through his window. Holmes looked out and saw three neighborhood brothers disappear around a corner. Their names? John Crimson, Mark Crimson and Paul Crimson.

The following day Holmes got a note on his door that read, simply: "? Crimson. He broke your window."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Four boys are playing football and one of them breaks a window](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/76112/four-boys-are-playing-football-and-one-of-them-breaks-a-window)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The note reads

> "question mark Crimson". So the culprit was Mark.